# Calculadora javascript (Poder utilizar mas de un calculo matematico a la vez)

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo una calculadora similar a la que trae android en javascript, ya tiene todo el estilo y esta funcionando bien, pero no me deja hacer mas de un calculo matematico... Alguien que sepa mas de javascript que yo que me diga que estoy haciendo mal? Lo agradeceria mucho... Todo mi codigo se encuentra en este codepen.io: [Enlace de codepen.io](https://codepen.io/PatrickDyD/pen/oONNQE)

Calculadora en pantalla completa: [Click aqui](https://codepen.io/PatrickDyD/full/oONNQE)

Por si acaso tambien lo agrego aqui:

```js
  var operandoa;
  var operandob;
  var operacion;
function init(){
  //variables
  var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
  var reset = document.getElementById('reset');
  var suma = document.getElementById('suma');
  var resta = document.getElementById('resta');
  var multiplicacion = document.getElementById('multiplicacion');
  var division = document.getElementById('division');
  var igual = document.getElementById('igual');
  var uno = document.getElementById('uno');
  var dos = document.getElementById('dos');
  var tres = document.getElementById('tres');
  var cuatro = document.getElementById('cuatro');
  var cinco = document.getElementById('cinco');
  var seis = document.getElementById('seis');
  var siete = document.getElementById('siete');
  var ocho = document.getElementById('ocho');
  var nueve = document.getElementById('nueve');
  var cero = document.getElementById('cero');
}
//Eventos de click
  uno.onclick = function(e){
  mioperacionaresolver.textContent = mioperacionaresolver.textContent + "1";
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent  + "1";
  }
  dos.onclick = function(e){
  mioperacionaresolver.textContent = mioperacionaresolver.textContent + "2";
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent  + "2";
  }
  tres.onclick = function(e){
  mioperacionaresolver.textContent = mioperacionaresolver.textContent + "3";
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent  + "3";
  }
  cuatro.onclick = function(e){
  mioperacionaresolver.textContent = mioperacionaresolver.textContent + "4";
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent  + "4";
  }
  cinco.onclick = function(e){
  mioperacionaresolver.textContent = mioperacionaresolver.textContent + "5";
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent  + "5";
  }
  seis.onclick = function(e){
  mioperacionaresolver.textContent = mioperacionaresolver.textContent + "6";
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent  + "6";
  }
  siete.onclick = function(e){
  mioperacionaresolver.textContent = mioperacionaresolver.textContent + "7";
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent  + "7";
  }
  ocho.onclick = function(e){
  mioperacionaresolver.textContent = mioperacionaresolver.textContent + "8";
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent  + "8";
  }
  nueve.onclick = function(e){
  mioperacionaresolver.textContent = mioperacionaresolver.textContent + "9";
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent  + "9";
  }
  cero.onclick = function(e){
  mioperacionaresolver.textContent = mioperacionaresolver.textContent + "0";
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent  + "0";
  }
  reset.onclick = function(e){
  resetear();
  }
  suma.onclick = function(e){
  mioperacionaresolver.textContent = mioperacionaresolver.textContent + "+";
  operandoa = resultado.textContent;
  operacion = "+";
  limpiar();
  }
  resta.onclick = function(e){
  mioperacionaresolver.textContent = mioperacionaresolver.textContent + "-";
  operandoa = resultado.textContent;
  operacion = "-";
  limpiar();
  }
  multiplicacion.onclick = function(e){
  mioperacionaresolver.textContent = mioperacionaresolver.textContent + "×";
  operandoa = resultado.textContent;
  operacion = "*";
  limpiar();
  }
  division.onclick = function(e){
  mioperacionaresolver.textContent = mioperacionaresolver.textContent + "÷";
  operandoa = resultado.textContent;
  operacion = "/";
  limpiar();
  }
  igual.onclick = function(e){
  operandob = resultado.textContent;
  resolver();
  }
function limpiar(){
  resultado.textContent = "";
}
function resetear(){
  mioperacionaresolver.textContent = "";
  resultado2.textContent = "";
  resultado.textContent = ""
  operandoa = 0;
  operandob = 0;
  operacion = "";
}
function resolver(){
  var res = 0;
  switch(operacion){
    case "+":
      res = parseFloat(operandoa) + parseFloat(operandob);
      break;
    case "-":
        res = parseFloat(operandoa) - parseFloat(operandob);
        break;
    case "*":
      res = parseFloat(operandoa) * parseFloat(operandob);
      break;
    case "/":
      res = parseFloat(operandoa) / parseFloat(operandob);
      break;
  }
  resultado2.textContent = res;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
 -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
   -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
        user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                              supported by Chrome and Opera */
}
html {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
body {
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-color: #3C4043
}
.contenedor-primario {
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
}
.contenedor-principal {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.contenedor-secundario {
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
}
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .contenedor-primario {
display: none;
  }
  .contenedor-secundario {
display: none;
  }
.contenedor-principal {
  width: 100%;
}
}
.contenedor {
  height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}
.contenedor2 {
  height: 60%;
  width: 78%!important;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #3C4043;
  float: left;
}
.contenedor3 {
  height: 60%;
  width: 22%!important;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #5D6166;
  float: left;
}
.col {
  background-color: #3C4043;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.col h1 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color:white;
  font-family:Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
}
.col-background:active {
background-color: #606466;
-moz-border-radius: 700px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 700px;
   border-radius: 700px;
-webkit-transition: background-color 10ms linear;
-moz-transition: background-color 10ms linear;
-o-transition: background-color 10ms linear;
-ms-transition: background-color 10ms linear;
transition: background-color 10ms linear;
}
.grisclaro {
  background-color: #5D6166;
}
.grisclaro2 {
  background-color: #5D6166;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.grisclaro2:active {
background-color: #7D8084;
-moz-border-radius: 700px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 700px;
   border-radius: 700px;
-webkit-transition: background-color 10ms linear;
-moz-transition: background-color 10ms linear;
-o-transition: background-color 10ms linear;
-ms-transition: background-color 10ms linear;
transition: background-color 10ms linear;
}
.colgris {
  background-color: #5D6166;
}
.col {
  padding-left: 0!important;
  padding-right: 0!important;
}
.num {
  height: 25%;
}
.num2 {
  height: 20%;
}
.resultado {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  color:#5D6166;
  top: 30%;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.operacion {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  color:black;
  top: 20%;
  font-size: 60px;
}
.operacionesinvisibles {
  display:none;
}
.resultado2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color:white!important;
}
.resultado2 .col {
  background-color: white!important;
}
.resultado2 .col h1 {
  color:black;
}
.operaciones {
  cursor:auto;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calc.css">
    <title>Calculadora</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="init();">
  <div class="contenedor-primario"></div>
  <div class="contenedor-principal">
    <div class="container-fluid contenedor">

      <div class="row resultado2">

        <div class="col operaciones">
          <h2 class="operacion"><span id="mioperacionaresolver"></span></h2>
          <h2 class="operacion operacionesinvisibles"><span id="resultado"></span></h2>
          <h2 class="resultado"><span id="resultado2"></span></h2>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid contenedor2">

      <div class="row num">
        <div class="col col-background" id="siete"><h1>7</h1></div>
        <div class="col col-background" id="ocho"><h1>8</h1></div>
        <div class="col col-background" id="nueve"><h1>9</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row num">
        <div class="col col-background" id="cuatro"><h1>4</h1></div>
        <div class="col col-background" id="cinco"><h1>5</h1></div>
        <div class="col col-background" id="seis"><h1>6</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row num">
        <div class="col col-background" id="uno"><h1>1</h1></div>
        <div class="col col-background" id="dos"><h1>2</h1></div>
        <div class="col col-background" id="tres"><h1>3</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row num">
        <div class="col col-background" id="borrar"><h1>C</h1></div>
        <div class="col col-background" id="cero"><h1>0</h1></div>
        <div class="col col-background" id="igual"><h1>=</h1></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid contenedor3">
      <div class="row num num2">
        <div class="col colgris" id="reset"><div class="grisclaro2"><h1>CE</h1></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row num num2">
        <div class="col colgris" id="division"><div class="grisclaro2"><h1>÷</h1></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row num num2">
        <div class="col colgris" id="multiplicacion"><div class="grisclaro2"><h1>×</h1></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row num num2">
        <div class="col colgris" id="resta"><div class="grisclaro2"><h1>-</h1></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row num num2">
        <div class="col colgris" id="suma"><div class="grisclaro2"><h1>+</h1></div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contenedor-secundario"></div>
<script src="calc2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

El problema es este...
Al hacer una operacion como 256*2, da el resultado correcto 512...

[image: primer resultado correcto]

Pero al querer hacer 256*2/2 me da 1, osea solamente toma la ultima operacion, como puedo modificar esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo creo que deberia tomar el primer resultado 256*2, resolverlo y luego hacer resultado/2, osea 512*2, alguna idea de como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Debes concretar mas tu pregunta, localizando el problema concreto que tienes. Esperar que alguien pruebe **todo** tu código, o que visite tu repositorio, es **mucho pedir**. Tal vez deberías consultar lo que es un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: No veo cual es el problema ... basta con ir ejecutando operaciones de izquierda a derecha, tal y como dices. Si te fijas, tu cadena solo contiene dígitos y caracteres de operación, que, casualmente, no son dígitos :-)

Comment: Es que no logro modificar el js para que ejecute las operaciones de izquierda a derecha como dices... intente haciendo esto luego de mostrar el resultado: operadoa = res; (que la variable operadoa obtenga el resultado) operadob = 0; (que el operadob se reinicie) y por ultimo operacion = ""; (quitando el simbolo de operacion para que vuelva a hacer una cuenta) pero no me estaria funcionando... me esta fallando algo?